# SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy already exists

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app, apps-development

I'm trying to configure an environment for apps for SharePoint (SharePoint 2013), 
Following  MS official  [docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ff607957.aspx) when I try to Run the following PS

```
add-pssnapin "Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell"
$AppPool = New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name CampariSettingsServiceAppPool -Account (Get-SPManagedAccount DOMain\user)
$App = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication -ApplicationPool $appPool -Name CampariSettingsServiceApps -DatabaseName SettingsServiceDB
$proxy = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy -ServiceApplication $App
Get-SPServiceInstance | where{$_.TypeName -eq "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service"} | Start-SPServiceInstance`
```

I get tthe error:

> New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy : A
>   SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy with id
>   '718596e0-df41-47e7-9117-1659b32fccf2' already exists. Only  one can
>   exist per farm. At line:4 char:10
>   + $proxy = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy -ServiceApplication $ ...
>   +          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (SPSubscriptionS...pplicationProxy:SPSubscriptionS...pplicationProxy)
>   [New-SPSubscript...pplicationProxy], InvalidOperation     Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy
>   WARNING: 'Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings
>   Service' is already started on server 'GRISPWL0'

Comment: Looks like you already have one. Did you install the farm manually or automatically?

Comment: Do you mean, configuration wizard?

Comment: Yeah, when you set up SharePoint you can choose to let the wizard do it for you or if you wanna set up all services by yourself. If you choose automatic installation, i'm very sure that the subscription setting service is included. You can find out what services are installed by running "get-spserviceapplication | select displayname, typename" in PowerShell.